# How to pass http://www.domainname.com as variable in htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

In my htaccess I have line

```
RewriteRule ^link-([0-9]+)-(.*).htm$ link.php?id=$1&link=$2 [L,NC]
```

For variable 2 there may be link as well. For example: `http://wwww.mysite.com/link-10-www.domain.com/click.htm?id=497&mid=13&prod=1&productname=name&target=http://www.domainname.com/name2.htm`. When i click  on this link, page not found message is displayed. 
Can anyone help me to find the solution?

Thanks for your co-operation

Answer (score 0):

Your RewriteRule and your example appear to be completely different.  Your RewriteRule shows a redirect matching a URL with `link-123-something.htm` in it, but the example URL you give goes to `click.htm`.

If you want `click.htm` to redirect somewhere, you'll need a separate RewriteRule.

Answer (score 0):

Your example will look at this query string:

```
link-10-www.domain.com/click.htm
```

and assign

```
$1 = 10
$2 = www.domain.com/click
```

and rewrite to

```
link.php?id=10&link=www.domain.com/click
```

If that is not happening, I would check whether you have a file called link.php.  Also, you have four w's in your example (wwww.mysite.com).

If you have a file called link.php, can you tell whether it gets called? Since it is being passed a link, perhaps it is redirecting to "www.domain.com/click" and that file doesn't exist?

Hard to tell without knowing more.